# Change Font and Color of JQuery Mobile via CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

In this question, I will not be giving the user any control over the color or font type in my JQuery list.

I am wondering if there is a way (without applying an entirely new theme) to change the font color of a JQuery list. This is currently using the default theme.

The class is named: *ui-content*

I have tried applying this CSS to the page, but the page still looks like the default JQuery Theme:

```
  .ui-content{
      font: "Helvetica Neue-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color:#A25254;
  }
```

Here is an example of one of the List View's Rows not changing font or color:
[image]

I would like the font to be *light*, not *bold*. I would also like to be able to change the icon on the left of the table.

Here is example code of how the table was constructed:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content" data-filter="true">
  <!--Begining of Table View-->
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/M7LLU/

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? It would be helpful.

Comment: Just added a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/M7LLU/

Comment: Are you sure it's not a specificity problem?
Example try `#page1 .ui-content h3 a` as a selector to increase specificity.

Comment: Well, do you think it would be a good idea to just modify the css that is the main theme for JQuery?

Comment: I'd rename the theme css and then modify it, yes.
Jquery mobile is really annoying when you want a custom design.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you know of any good iOS 7 themed jQuery? (I have seen the flat design, any others?)

Comment: @JakeChasan Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/M7LLU/1/

Comment: And is there any way to remove the blue color when the cell is pressed down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options for that. First thing you should use id for that.  `<div role="main" class="ui-content" data-filter="true" id="Something">`

So Css will be something like this:

```
#Something{
    font: "Helvetica Neue-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#A25254;
}
```

And Another option is 'inspect' your div and find out what's your div's class.

You will find something like this `.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper`
The bold one is (i checked on google chrome. if it's bold it's one you should write)
if bold one is : .ui-panel-wrapper
Example :

```
.ui-panel-wrapper .ui-content{
    yourCss:ishere;
}
```